# Is calling a model from a view in codeigniter bad?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, codeigniter-2

Ok I have been creating a small test site using code igniter and so far I have my Login and logouts done. Those all follow proper MVC I think with logic in the controller, the actual work in the model and the presentation in the view. However I have come to a problem when doing stuff like including a news feed in the front-site, no login required. I was thinking of just putting a call in the Home view to the model responsible for displaying news feed stuff. Is this bad practice or not? Basically what is the best way for displaying stuff that is dynamic like a news feed or even a users photos when logged in?

Comment: It is generally frowned upon.  You should have your controller talk to your model and gather the data to be printed into a variable that will be passed to your view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very wrong.

In an ideal world all your functions, data calls, manipulation, data inserts etc would be in the models.

The controller is used to decide which calls from the models are required and pass data back and forth.  It's at this point that the controller can gather the information required for the views and pass them forward.

The only logic you should have in your views is if/else and for each loops.  I 'prep' all my data before it goes to the view so date formatting, empty value handling etc is also done so my views are nothing more than plain HTML with a smattering of name; ?> type variables.

Comment: That is not what controllers or views are responsible for. Please learn what each part in MVC is **actually** responsible for.

Comment: In the context of Codeigniter this is how it is handled.  You mention as much below.

Answer (score 0):

In correctly implemented MVC-inspired design pattern, the views are responsible for acquiring information from model layer and creating a response (made from multiple templates, if required). This means, that for views to request data from model layer is the correct thing to do.

What you should avoid is operation, that alter the state of model layer, because that part is responsibility of the controller.

Another thing that should be noted is that this applies only if you have real view instances. What CodeIgniter calls "views" are nothing but bunch of dumb templates. Templates should not request any data from anywhere.

Comment: This means View is acting like a controller which just feels wrong on all levels. I'm not stating it's wrong as these things are subjective, just in my experience Controller should know about what data is required for the route/resource/request and return a HTTP response or pass to some View.

Comment: No. The controller is responsible **only** for handling the user's input, if you are doing the MVC correctly.

Comment: There is no "correctly" in web apps, as you know MVC is from desktop anyway where things are different. But in webapps there's only "sensible approach" and that is subjective. But to debate it, a controller should be in charge of request and response and everything in between, albeit asking other things to perform tasks - Model, Service, etc, and ultimately returning a response or loading a view. I don't think it's sensible for View to call Model in a web application scenario. You way means controllers are almost just routers and form handlers? Seems weird.

Comment: View **classes** are what should be responsible for the response. It seems that you are confusing "templates" and "views". The controllers are responsible for altering the state of the business later and are actually the smallest part of MVC triad.

Comment: I guess whether "view" calls model or not then depends on the scenario, if it just needs basic templates to output to the page, or if it needs a full presentation "layer" which can then call Model.